# Add a 2 value tuple to dict as key:value

Tags: python

I have a tuple, like `('key1', 'value1')` that I want to add that to a dictionary so it is like `{'key1': 'value1'}` but not doing something like `dictionary[t[0]] = t[1]`.

The context is as follows, I have a recurrence rule that looks like:

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20120620T233000Z;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=WE,TH
```

And I want to have a dict like:

```
recurrence = {
    'freq' : 'weekly',
    'until' : '20120620T233000Z',
    'interval' : '2',
    'byday' : 'we,th'
}
```

And I'm doing something like this:

```
for rule in recurrence.split(';'):
    r = rule.split('=')
    rules[r[0]] = r[1]
```

And I don't like it at all. Is there a more pythonic way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
rules.update(rule.split('=', 1) for rule in recurrence.split(';'))
```

This is if the dict `rules` already exists; otherwise use

```
rules = dict(rule.split('=', 1) for rule in recurrence.split(';'))
```

This works because the `dict` constructor and `dict.update` both accept an iterator yielding key/value pairs.

Comment: `.partition('=')[::2]` if missing '=' is valid/may be ignored

Comment: This comment is what I love about SO. I was looking for a clean way to avoid the "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 1; 2 is required" when unpacking a string that had missing values such as this: 'user_id="123",access_token="XXXXXX",timestamp'. This comment was an "ah-ha" moment that has taught me something very valuable.

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` function will transform your tuple of tuples into a key: value dictionary. How about this,

```
t=((1,2),(3,4))
dict(t)
{1:2,3:4}
```

Answer (score 1):

use dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> strs="FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20120620T233000Z;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=WE,TH"
>>> dic={key: value for key, value in (rule.split("=") for rule in strs.split(";"))}
>>> print(dic)

{'BYDAY': 'WE,TH', 'FREQ': 'WEEKLY', 'INTERVAL': '2', 'UNTIL': '20120620T233000Z'}
```